# Current font missing characters with macron

Tags: bug, design

[image]

Latin letters with macron are currently not rendered correctly on this site. The cause is that this site is using a version of Open Sans hosted by Stackexchange server, which only contains Latin-1 characters.

As letters with macron are essential in some rōmaji system, replacing the font file with a version includes Latin Extended (or fuller) glyph set is proposed.

Such files seem available at [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans).

---

Test field:

> ## A Ā I Ī U Ū E Ē O Ō
>
> ## a ā i ī u ū e ē o ō
>
> A Ā I Ī U Ū E Ē O Ō
>   a ā i ī u ū e ē o ō